# Is it possible to attach a passive url to a hyperlink such that the passive url is regarded as a refferar url by the target tracker?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, pdf, latex, tex

I want to create a link in my pdf book or my site. When the user click the link, it will visit to a target site using a traffic tracker.

I am interested to take advantage of this tracker by manipulating my link so that the tracker will see the incoming request comes from a certain url which actually does not initiate the request.

In other words, is it possible to attach a passive url to a hyperlink pointing to a target url such that the passive url is regarded as a refferar url by the target tracker?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You would have to run a forwarder of your own that the PDF linked to. This would then link/JS-redirect to the tracker with itself as the referrer.

Easier for tracking purposes would be to add a do-nothing parameter like `?camefrompdf=true` to the target URL.